# How to determine if checkbox is selected using PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello guys I just want to ask what's my wrong with my code because what I am trying to do is determine if checkbox is selected or not. If selected assign it to 'Y' if not to 'N'.
Here's my code

#### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cash_delivery" />
```

#### PHP

```
$cash_delivery = $this->input->post('cash_delivery');

if(isset($cash_delivery)){
   echo 'Y';
}else{
   echo 'N';
}

exit;
```

**My problem is if I unchecked the checkbox it return to 'Y' if checked also to 'Y'**

That's all guys thanks in advance. By the way I am using Codeigniter

Comment: `if($cash_delivery == FALSE){//logic}`

Comment: Don't put `SOLVED` phrase on the title, If any of these given answers is correct, mark it, otherwise post the correct answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($cash_delivery)){
   echo 'Y';
}else{
   echo 'N';
}
```

will always return true because of previous statement:

```
$cash_delivery = $this->input->post('cash_delivery');
```

You should check

```
if ($cash_delivery==false)
{
  //do domething
}
else 
{
  //do some other thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$cash_delivery` is always set as it has been initialized here, `$cash_delivery = $this->input->post('cash_delivery');`. Try checking value of `$cash_delivery` instead of `isset()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks guys for the answer but I found the solution.

Instead of using for checking
**$cash_delivery = $this->input->post('cash_delivery');**

I used the **$_POST['cash_delivery']**

This is what I did:

```
if(isset($_POST['cash_delivery'])){
   $val_delivery = 'Y';
}else{
   $val_delivery = 'N';
}
```